# Presenting particular TabBarItem - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `UITabBarController` with four `TabBaritem`, and I have leftMenu in every ViewConrollers. The left menu selection leads to present each ChildViewController. So I used NavigationController to present every child view controller while tapping left menu rows.
But the problem is, the selected `TabBarItem` doesn't change and the new selected `TabBarItem` presenting in the same `ViewController` that which controller I selected the `ChildViewContrller`.

eg:  If I am in secVC and select left menu for navigate to firstVC
 it present firstVc in sec tabBarItem.and after some functionality if I
 am again tapping sec tabBarItem it will show the firstVC. But I have
 to show the FirstVc in First tabBarItem

My left menu selection code is,

```
if sender.tag == 0 {
    let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")as? HomeVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVc!, animated: true)
}
else if sender.tag == 1 {
    let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TileDetailsVC")as? TileDetailsVC
    navVc?.leftMenuPrdctId = 1
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVc!, animated: true)
}
else if sender.tag == 2 {
    let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OrderHistoryVC")as? OrderHistoryVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVc!, animated: true)
}
else if sender.tag == 3 {
    let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TileDetailsVC")as? TileDetailsVC
    navVc?.leftMenuPrdctId = 3
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVc!, animated: true)
}
else if sender.tag == 5 {
    let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC")as! SettingsVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navVc, animated: true)
}
```

Anyone please help me for how to present a particular tabBarItem while tapping left menu Row.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as said by Diksha Bhargava, just change the selected index of the UITabBarController and the new view controller will show.  Changing the selected index will change the selected view controller, and the selected view controller is the one displayed in the UITabBarController and whose tab is selected.

So changing the UITabBarController's selected index changes the view controller and selected tab.

So doing:

```
yourUITabBarController.selectedIndex=x
//where x is the index of the desired view controller 
//in the array of viewControllers the tab bar has
```

(by default selected view controller should correspond to the selected tab, including as it changes)

will actually display the view controller at that tab and use its tab bar item in the tab bar.
Easy way to programmatically change the displayed view controller of the tab bar controller.

You can check out apple's docs on UITabController and look at the info on:

selectedIndex

selectedViewController

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate to tabar controller directly. Try this:

```
 let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nav = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! UINavigationController
       self.navigationcontroller.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tabBarController selectedIndex to the corresponding tab number. For example if you are navigating from tab 1 to tab 2 you have to set selectedIndex = 1 as index starts from 0 . So tab1 index is 0 tab4 index is 3 and so on. For instance:

```
yourTabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 // put your desired index number here to change the selected tab bar item
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: this will change selection color only.Please refer my edited question(example)

Comment: Try setting the selectedViewController to root like this after setting the selected index
let navController = yourTabBarController?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
        navController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Comment: What is selectedVC here?

Comment: Its a view controller which may return the "More" navigation controller if it exists.